# Python: How to handle indirect references when inserting into PostgreSQL-tables?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I have two .csv files named "country.csv", which looks like this:

```
Country Code,Country Name,Country-ID
US,United States,0
DE,Germany,1
AU,Australia,2
CZ,Czechia,3
CA,Canada,4
AR,Argentina,5
BR,Brazil,6
PT,Portugal,7
GB,United Kingdom,8
IT,Italy,9
GG,Guernsey,10
RO,Romania,11
```

and "users.csv", which looks like this:

```
User-ID,Age,username,Country-ID
1,,madMeerkat6#yHazv,0
2,18.0,innocentUnicorn8#eCMNj,1
3,,jubilantStork8#YgoL-,0
4,17.0,hushedOatmeal4#y5QVW,0
5,,thrilledRhino7#3PYN3,0
6,61.0,insecureCaviar4#xosWW,0
7,,artisticGarlic3#Sla7S,2
8,,dearMandrill9#c1J0m,1
9,,cynicalDinosaur3#0wSxC,0
10,26.0,gloomyCake2#eRcdC,0
11,14.0,sincereCockatoo6#eDuI_,0
```

I had to generate the following PostgreSQL-tables using (precisely) the commands:

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
    ISO_3166 CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    CountryName VARCHAR(256),
    CID varchar(16)
);
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Username VARCHAR(256),
    DoB DATE,
    Age INT,
    ISO_3166 CHAR(2) REFERENCES Country (ISO_3166)
);
```

and now I want to insert the values from the csv-files into the tables. My attempt was the following Python script:

```
import csv
import sys
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import extras
import re
import ast
from datetime import date


def csv_to_dictionary(csv_name, delimiter):
    input_file = csv.DictReader(open(csv_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8'), delimiter=delimiter)
    return input_file

sql_con = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', port='5432', database="XYZ", user='postgres', password='XYZ')
cursor = sql_con.cursor()


country_dictionary = csv_to_dictionary("country.csv", ',')
for row in country_dictionary:
    cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO country (iso_3166, countryname, cid)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s) """, (row["Country Code"], row["Country Name"], row["Country-ID"]))

user_dictionary = csv_to_dictionary("user.csv", ',')
for row in user_dictionary:
    if row["Age"] == "" and row["Country-ID"] == "0":
        cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO users (uid, username)  VALUES (%s, %s) """, (int(row["User-ID"]), row["username"]))
    elif row["Age"] != "" and row["Country-ID"] == "0":
        cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO users (uid, username, age)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s) """, (int(row["User-ID"]), row["username"], int(float(row["Age"]))))
    elif row["Age"] == "" and row["Country-ID"] != "0":
        cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO users (uid, username, iso_3166)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s) """, (int(row["User-ID"]), row["username"], row["Country-ID"]))
    else:
        cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO users (uid, username, age, iso_3166)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) """, (int(row["User-ID"]), row["username"], int(float(row["Age"])), row["Country-ID"]))


sql_con.commit()

cursor.close()
sql_con.close()
```

The insertion of the data from "country.csv" works fine, however, the problem here is that "ISO_3166" in the table "Users" references "ISO_3166" in the table "Country", but users.csv" only contains the "Country-ID" in ( which is the same as the "Country-ID" in the "users.csv"). I know that there is a 1-1 correspondences between "Country" and "Country-ID" (in "country.csv"), but I do not see how to obtain the "Country" from the corresponding "Country_ID".

Could you please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Grab it from the dictionary but pandas may be a better tool

Comment: By necessity `country.cid` must also be unique. So just declare is as such, then drop `iso_3166` column and add `cid` to `users` table and alter the FK to refer to `country.cid`. You may also want to look into the Postgres `copy` statement  or the psql `\copy` command to load the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install and use pandas you get to use table-like structures (called "DataFrames" and referred by "df" in the scripts) that will do most of the heavy lifting for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

def read_csv(file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    return df

def create_country_id_to_iso_mapper(country_df):
    mapper = {}
    for index, row in country_df.iterrows():
        mapper[row['Country-ID']] = row['ISO_3166']
    return mapper

def insert_data_into_table(table_name, df):
    sql_con = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', port='5432', database="XYZ", user='postgres', password='XYZ')
    cursor = sql_con.cursor()

    if table_name == "users":
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            row_age = row["Age"]
            row_country_id = row["Country-ID"]
            row_iso_3166 = row["ISO_3166"]

            if pd.isna(row_age) and row_country_id == "0":
                query = f"INSERT INTO users (uid, username) VALUES ({row['User-ID']}, '{row['username']}')"
            elif not pd.isna(row_age) and row_country_id == "0":
                query = f"INSERT INTO users (uid, username, age) VALUES ({row['User-ID']}, '{row['username']}', {row_age})"
            elif pd.isna(row_age) and row_country_id != "0":
                query = f"INSERT INTO users (uid, username, iso_3166) VALUES ({row['User-ID']}, '{row['username']}', '{row_iso_3166}')"
            else:
                query = f"INSERT INTO users (uid, username, age, iso_3166) VALUES ({row['User-ID']}, '{row['username']}', {row_age}, '{row_iso_3166}')"

            cursor.execute(query)

    elif table_name == "country":
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            query = f"INSERT INTO country (Country-ID, ISO_3166) VALUES ({row['Country-ID']}, '{row['ISO_3166']}')"
            cursor.execute(query)

    sql_con.commit()
    cursor.close()
    sql_con.close()

country_df = read_csv("country.csv")
users_df = read_csv("user.csv")

country_id_to_iso_mapper = create_country_id_to_iso_mapper(country_df)

# Update the 'Country-ID' column in the users DataFrame with the corresponding 'ISO_3166' values
users_df['ISO_3166'] = users_df['Country-ID'].map(country_id_to_iso_mapper)

# Insert data into the 'country' and 'users' tables
insert_data_into_table("country", country_df)
insert_data_into_table("users", users_df)
```

This reads the CSV files, maps country IDs to ISO codes, then updates the "users" DataFrame taht mapping. Finally it inserts to the country table and inserts the now updated data into "users" table